# How To Create A Dynamic Webflow

Tags: grails, dynamic, spring-webflow

Say I have a Category domain and a Question Domain and a Category hasMany questions.

I need to first present the user with a list of categories. They can select any number of categories. Say they select 3 categories. So then they would be shown three screens of questions, one screen with the questions from each of the 3 categories they selected.

So all of these different possible states have to be determined dynamically. How can this be done with a webflow?

Is there a better way to this?

(I'm using Grails 2.x).